# npm install failing on Windows due to #branch syntax?

Tags: node.js, windows, git, npm, mingw32

Running Windows 7, MinGW32, Node 5.7.0, npm 3.6.0

My package.json has the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
}
```

Running npm install gets the following error:

```
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 4.0: fatal: ambiguous argument    
'4.0':unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

But if I run this:

```
$ npm install "gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
```

It (usually) succeeds.

Based on searching around, I thought perhaps the '#' needed to be escaped, but I've tried `\#` and all kinds of single and double quote combinations with no luck. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

thanks!

**Edit:**
I should mention that using the same package.json on OS X always runs fine.

**Update:**
A colleague mentioned she was having trouble pointing to github repos in package.json and had to prefix it like so: `"some-package" : "github:someuser/somepackage"`

This syntax also solved my issue on windows:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
}
```

So problem solved but would love to know what the explanation is if there are any takers.

Comment: Have you tried `"gulp" : "~4.0.0"`  ? Or just install it using `npm install gulp --save-dev` and edit the version in the package.json

Comment: `"~4.0.0"` doesn't work because 3.x is the latest version on the main branch. Yeah, I can get around it myself no problem, but I need to share this package.json w colleagues and need a reliable npm install without unusual steps.